# mysql - look through known databases?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of known database name that I would like to apply the same sql command.

It is as simple as:

use my_database;
inset into table (col)
values ('value');

I would like to use a for loop or some sort to replace the "use my_database" part.

I have googled but most answer as about "iterate through all databases", not a portion of known databases.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you dealing directly with MySQL or are you using some sort of programming language on top like Java, PHP, Ruby or something?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention. I am using Navicat so I am dealing directly with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to use the `use database` command to interact with a specific schema. You can prefix table names as part of the insert query:

`insert into schema_name.table_name (col) values ('value');` will produce the same end result.

If you're dealing solely with MySQL what you're trying to do may prove a bit cumbersome, although you could loop through all the desired schema/table combinations with a stored procedure (although if this is only a one time thing, it may be a bit overkill)

If you are interacting with MySQL from an application with write privileges, you could:

> 1. Build and array with schema names

The specifics would be language dependant but for example with PHP you'd do something like this:
`$schemas = array('schema_one', 'schema_two', 'schema_three');`

> 2. Loop through the schema array

Again, in PHP you'd use something like `foreach` as in:

```
foreach($schemas as $s)
{
    $stmt = "insert into ".$s.".table_name (col) values('".$value."')";
    // Here, you'd actually run $stmt against MySQL to run the insert. 
}
```

This is an extremely rough example, I used PHP because that's where I spend 99% of my coding time, but you could use any other programming language to achieve the same thing

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I will give "insert into schema_name.table_name (col) values ('value');" a try.